# How can I do Incremental Analysis in Sonarlint Ecllipse Plug in?

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I recently installed Sonarlint plug in for my ecllipse. It is fantastic plug in and it helps a lot while you are writing code. But our standard practice is to check whether my new code is creating any issue using incremental mode of Sonar.

Can I use Sonarlint plug in to do incremental analysis? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be possible very soon with the upcoming version 1.2 of SonarLint for Eclipse and IntelliJ. You will be able to check locally the new issues by [organizing them by creation date](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-19).

Later, a connected mode will also be introduced to track new issues comparing to a SonarQube server.